# Distance of a point from a straight line

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, education

For the straight line point distance there are several proofs. Several years ago I have proved (but I no longer remember the proof), the point-right distance by remembering that for a line $$r: ax+by+c=0$$ $\mathbf{ \hat n}=(a,b)$  is perpendicular to $r$ .I kindly ask if someone can answer me with simple proof for 15-year-old students in high school of a scientific high school. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to use vectors? If you don't then you can just find a perpendicular line to $r$ that passes through a specific point and then the intersection of that perpendicular line and $r$ will give you a point on $r$. Finally just calculate the distance from the point of intersection on $r$ and the point that you've been given on the start. Just generalize this. Keep in mind that if you have to use vectors, $\hat{n}=(a,b)$ is not perpendicular to $r$. In fact, what is more commonly used notation is $\vec{d}=(a,b)$, is parallel to line $r$.

Comment: The vector that is perpendicular to $\vec{d}$, let's call it $\vec{n}$, you can find by solving $(a,b)\cdot \vec{n}=0$. There should be infinitely many solutions, but they will be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the picture below.

[image]

On one hand the area of the triangle $ABC$ is $$\frac{1}{2}|BC||AC|=\frac{1}{2}|y_1-y_0||x_1-x_0|.$$

On the other hand the same area is $$\frac{1}{2}|AB|h=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|y_1-y_0|^2+|x_1-x_0|^2}h,$$ where $h$ is the distance of $C=(x_0,y_0)$ to the line. Hence
\begin{equation}|y_1-y_0||x_1-x_0|=\sqrt{|y_1-y_0|^2+|x_1-x_0|^2}h\ \ \ \ (*)\end{equation}

Now, since $A,B$ belong to the line and its equation is $ax+by+c=0$, we have

$$ax_0+by_1+c=0\Rightarrow y_1=\frac{-c-ax_0}{b}$$
$$ax_1+by_0+c=0\Rightarrow x_1=\frac{-c-by_0}{a}$$

Thus, $|y_1-y_0|=\frac{d}{|b|}$ and $|x_1-x_0|=\frac{d}{|a|}$, where $d=|ax_0+by_0+c|$.

Finally, by $(*)$, we have $$\frac{d}{|b|}\frac{d}{|a|}=\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{|b|^2}+\frac{d^2}{|a|^2}}h\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ h=\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Comment: Why $|y_1-y_0|=\frac{d}{|b|}$ and $|x_1-x_0|=\frac{d}{|a|}$ and $d=|ax_0+by_0+c|$?

Comment: @Sebastiano, $|y_1-y_0|=|\frac{-c-ax_0}{b}-y_0|=|\frac{-c-ax_0-by_0}{b}|=\frac{d}{|b|}$